# Is it possible to use amCharts5: Simple Pie Chart, but not with percentages?

Tags: javascript, php, pie-chart, amcharts5

I started using this library, and I liked it. I was wondering if anyone had the need for instead of showing the data in percentage, to show the real data without going to its corresponding %.

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/simple-pie-chart/

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

You could make a label with your data in it, like so:

```
  pieSeries.labels.template.setAll({
    radius: 25,
    inside: true,
    fontSize: 10,
    text: '{count}'
  })
```

Put your real data in the 'text', like I did with count.